# i am trying to get the max number

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am tying to get the value of the max number. But it is not working.

```
    drqry = "SELECT max(num) FROM tbCVinfo WHERE cvabbrv LIKE '%" & abbrv & "%' and `year` LIKE '%" & year & "%'"
    'drqry = "SELECT max(cvno) FROM tbCVinfo WHERE cvno LIKE '%" & cvstr & "%'"

    cmd2.CommandText = drqry
    cmd2.Connection = con

    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader

    Dim result As String = ""

    If dr.Read() Then
        dr.Close()

        cv = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())  ''''i am having an error in this part. it says "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." upon checking all datas in the database, I don't have null values
        cv = cv + 1
        If cv >= 0 And cv <= 9 Then
            result = "000" & cv
```

Comment: That error message indicates that `ExecuteScalar` is returning `DBNull.Value` and it's the `Convert.ToInt32` call that is failing. That means that there are no records that match your `WHERE` clause, so the result of `MAX` is `NULL`.

Comment: What is the data type of the `year` column?  Years are obviously numbers so it should be numeric but you can't use `LIKE` with anything but text, so that might be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the maximum number then the first query should instead be:

```
drqry = "SELECT max(num) FROM tbCVinfo WHERE cvabbrv LIKE '%" & abbrv & "%' and `year` LIKE '%" & year & "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. and yes, it is now running. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
    drqry = "SELECT max(num) FROM tbCVinfo WHERE cvno LIKE '%" & cvstr & "%'"

    cmd2.CommandText = drqry
    cmd2.Connection = con

    Dim result As String = ""

    cv = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
```